# How integrate lua in visual studio 2017?

Tags: lua

I'm a student and I wanna start learning this language, I have some experience with C++ projects, it's very easy create, debug you project, add some files. How i can do all of this stuff with lua? Highlighted syntaxes, debug tools, very useful.

I know that on official site you can use lua53.exe file and compile in console, but may be exist more easy way to do it in studio? Also i know that exist a lot of other IDE that can accomplish that kind of stuff, but i get used to VS.

Comment: Google for "zero-brain"

Answer (score 0):

You can use visual-code,
or IntelliJ (with [lua](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5055-lua) extensions).